# Sending messages to multiple numbers using twilio Passthrough API

Tags: javascript, node.js, sms, twilio

I am using twilio to send messages to multiple phone numbers in a single API call.

```
client.notify.services(notifyServiceSid)
  .notifications.create({
    toBinding: JSON.stringify([
      binding_type: 'sms', address: '** First phone number here **',
      binding_type: 'sms', address: '** Second phone number here **'
    ]),
    body: 'You just sent your first message with the Passthrough API!'
  })
  .then(notification => console.log(notification.sid))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

The above example code snippet sends same message('You just sent your first message with the Passthrough API!') to array of phone numbers though what I'm trying to do is send different message to each phone number. That doesn't seems to possible with above code snippet. I couldn't find anything in the given blog either: [Passthrough API](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/bulk-sms-with-one-api-request.html). So is there anyway to send different message to each phone number. I also have an implementation that sends different message to each recipient:

```
const prepareSendingMessages = async (body) => {
    //parse message input and send message in loop
    try {
        console.log(body.data)
        for (const sms of body.data.messages) {
            await sendMessage(sms.to, sms.message)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

};

const sendMessage = async (to, message) => {
    let messageResult = await client.messages
        .create({
            body: message,
            from: process.env.TWILIO_NUMBER,
            to
        });

    console.log(messageResult);

    return true;
};
```

But I am looking if it is possible through [Twilio's Passthrough API](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/bulk-sms-with-one-api-request.html)

Comment: doesn't look like but you can specify the message for the [channel](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/notification-resource#code-send-custom-notifications-by-channel)

Comment: @fubar please add more details if possible as I don't have channel or even phone numbers stored in database, I received phone numbers from my web app, and those can be different each time.

Comment: What I'm saying is it is not possible to send different text messages to different numbers using this method. But if user1 reads the message as SMS and user2 reads it with fcm then they can be different. **but** if user1 goes to facebook it will be the same as for user2. So nope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was trying yo do is send multiple message to different phone numbers, while each phone number containing a different body, well I had an option of [Twilio's Passthrough](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/bulk-sms-with-one-api-request.html) API but the problem here is you can't change the body of messages for individual number. So what I did used [Twilio's send-message API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages), calling API call for each number with different message body for each number. So it is not possible to send multiple messages with single API call while each message containing different body, at least with [Twilio's Passthrough API](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/bulk-sms-with-one-api-request.html).

Answer (score 1):

You use the messages resource for that.

How to send an SMS
https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages

Comment: Already doing the same thing, but it is a separate rest API for each phone number, What I am trying to achieve is that is it possible to do it with [Twilio's Passthrough  API](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/bulk-sms-with-one-api-request.html) but message body will be different for each recipient

Comment: It is not possible.